# Manifolds with 'bad metrics' (reference request)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

While studying some differential geometry, a thought crossed my mind that I am sure has been considered before, but I cannot find a reference for it.

What can be said about spaces for which the metric has pathological behaviour? I know that this is playing fast and loose with the terminology, but bear with me.

In particular I am curious about generalised metrics that change signature. My rough idea of an example is $\mathbb{R}^2$ where we have a notion of length that is asymptotically Minkowskian, but near to the origin is Euclidean.
For a vector $v$ with components $(v_x, v_y)$, let 
$$
||v||^2 = f(v_x^2 + v_y^2) v_x^2 + v_y^2 = f(v \cdot v) v_x^2 + v_y^2
$$
where the $\cdot$ is the ordinary Euclidean dot product, and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some nice function with 
$$
\lim_{r \to 0^+} f(r) = 1\\
\lim_{r \to \infty} f(r) = -1
$$

Examples of such an $f$ include
$$
2e^{-r^2} - 1
$$
and
$$
\frac{1-r}{r+1}
$$

Of course it no longer makes sense to call this a metric as it's not a symmetric bilinear form. I guess we could define
$$
\left<u, v\right> = f(u \cdot v) u_xv_x + u_yv_y
$$
but the notation would not be appropriate.

Does anyone know if such signature-changing spaces have a name? Where can I learn more about them?

Comment: Every "quadratic-form" definition of a "metric" I've encountered assumes non-degeneracy at each point, in which case the phenomenon you describe cannot occur: the signature of a "smooth metric" is constant on connected components.

Comment: The same is true of my experience. This is a different thing altogether but seems a natural enough generalisation, so I thought the terminology would be appropriate.